# How do I disable registry backup in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry, windows-backup

There are no such tasks in Task Scheduler, but C:\windows\config\regback folder occupies 100 MB of space and if I delete it, then it appears again.

Answer (score 0):

- Goto Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools.
- Select **Task Scheduler** and click **Open** and in the left zone, expand **Task Scheduler Library**, **Microsoft**, **Windows**.
- Double-click **Registry** and select **RegIdleBackup**.
- In the **Actions** zone, click **Disable**.

Comment: As I've said, I don't have such task